# Alternative to simplexml_load_string for PHP4

Tags: php, xml, string, simplexml

I am using `simplexml_load_string` for XML string interpreting to object from results of a REST API. It's working fine in my local server, which is using PHP5. But my hosting service provider is giving me PHP4.

For that I need to change the way of interpreting XML string to object to another method, which I don't know how to do.

Can anyone edit it for me? http://codepad.viper-7.com/OYxzLD

Comment: I didn't think it was possible that someone would still be offering PHP4 - that probably hasn't seen security fixes for some years. I strongly recommend you switch to another host - PHP5.3 minimum.

Comment: Thanks @halfer ...i will change ...before this i didn't thought of a service provider giving older version of php...

Comment: It's not actually _Yahoo_ offering PHP4 hosting, surely? They certainly ought to know better.

Comment: It's what am getting on when i put phpinfo();..

Comment: PHP     :  Version 4.3.11
System :  FreeBSD hostingprod.com 4.11-YAHOO-20070605 FreeBSD                   4.11-YAHOO-20070605 #0: i386

Comment: I just [found a similar `phpinfo` to yours](http://www.skeensconstruction.com/phpinfo.php) - it's just a build of FreeBSD (a Unix-like OS) - and a very old one too, from 2007! Yahoo probably released their own version of it. Anyway avoid it, and get another host.

Comment: I see you've added a link asking someone to convert your code. That's not a good idea for several reasons: (1) you risk getting downvoted for it, since (2) it is better to ask for _help_ rather than for someone to do your work for you, and (3) you appear to want to carry on using PHP4.

Comment: If you really do want to use DOM as per Suresh's answer, then try converting it yourself, and ask a new question if you get stuck.

Comment: sure @halfer!...But i asked the service provider to change the version of php instead of messing with the codes...They instantly changed it for me...:)

Comment: Good. Out of interest, can you link to the firm, and/or supply their name? I'd like to see what a PHP4 host looks like `:)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DOM](http://php.net/dom), which support PHP4 for parsing XML.

Please see the below example:

---

```
XML Data:
<data>
<Report ID="1">
    <Date>REVIEW</Date>
    <AuthorID>1</AuthorID>
</Report>
<Report ID="2">
    <Date>REVIEW</Date>
    <AuthorID>2</AuthorID>
</Report>
</data>
```

---

```
<?php
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load( 'data.xml' );

$searchNode = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName( "Report" );

foreach( $searchNode as $searchNode )
{
    $valueID = $searchNode->getAttribute('ID');

    $xmlDate = $searchNode->getElementsByTagName( "Date" );
    $valueDate = $xmlDate->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $xmlAuthorID = $searchNode->getElementsByTagName( "AuthorID" );
    $valueAuthorID = $xmlAuthorID->item(0)->nodeValue;

    echo "$valueID - $valueDate - $valueAuthorID\n";
}
?>
```

---

Output:

1 - REVIEW - 1
2 - REVIEW - 2

---

Comment: Yes i know that...but please give me an example...i tried by using DOM ...but am confused in using that...